# Dompdf text-align: justify fails when using subscript

Tags: dompdf

For our chemistry conference, we use dompdf for abstract submission: users can submit their abstract using an online form, and can preview the pdf output.

There is a specific issue where the text-justification fails (too much space at right border) on the line of text where the user used subscript:

```
<? require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$html =
  '
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    </head>
  <body style="font-family: \'dejavu sans\'; line-height: 95%;">

  <div style="text-align: justify;font-size:9pt;">
    <p>To account for solvation effects and ligand substitution reactions, the polarizable continuum model (IEFPCM) option, explicit water molecules and sulphate ions, and different arrangement of ligands were employed, respectively. The D<sub>2</sub>O/H<sub>2</sub>O exchange influence on the simulated and experimentally observed Raman spectra was evaluated. The data of molecular modeling indicate the formation of octahedral iron(III) complex with thiocyanate and sulphate anions and (or) water molecules. </p>
    </div></body>

  </html>';

$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper('a5', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$pdfoutput = $dompdf->output(); 
$filename = 'preview_subscript.pdf'; 
$fp = fopen('previews/'.$filename, "a"); 
fwrite($fp, $pdfoutput); 
fclose($fp); 
?>
```

PDF output: http://www.chemcys.be/previews/preview_subscript.pdf

Notice the extra white space on the fourth line.

When I remove the subscript, the issue disappears.
Also when I use the Arial font the issue disappears, but we really need the dejavu sans font for support of unicode characters.

Comment: This is a known issue, no resolution is yet available. See https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/547

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at least I'm aware now that I shouldn't search any further for a resolution.

Comment: just using paragraf atribute with style `style="text-align: center;"`